# Can you retrieve Amazon Glacier inventory in Expedited mode?

Tags: c#, .net, aws-sdk, amazon-glacier

taking snapshot of a Glacier archive inventory takes 4 hrs. Is there Expedited mode for this operation (similar to download job)?

I use AWS SDK .NET